# ajax serialize gives different strings and form autosave doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, autosave

I am trying to implement an autosave functionality using ajax and php. Here is my script:

```
function autosave() {
    alert($("#myform").serialize());
    $.ajax({
        url: "form_creator.php",
        data: $("#myform").serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            if(data && data == 'success') {
                alert("saved");
                // Save successfully completed, no need to do anything
            }else{
                alert(data);
                // Save failed, report the error if you desire
                // ....
            }
        }// end successful POST function
    }); // end jQuery ajax call
 // end setting up the autosave on every form on the page
 }// end function autosave()
 setInterval(autosave, 5000);
```

The problem is that I am getting different strings in the first alert and in the second one (in else section). In the first alert, the string seems to be correct with key=value&key2=value2.... but the second alert in else section gives me all html page. Is this correct behaviour? The autosave functionality doesn't work... Am I missing something?

```
<?php if((isset($_POST['sub'])) || (isset($_POST["autosave_check"]))) 
{ //save to db
}else{

?>

<form  action="" method="post" id="myform" class="ajax_form" name="myform" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <ul class="sorting dd-list" id="my_list">
        //generate inputs           
    </ul>


    <input type="hidden" name="chbox" class='hdbox' id="chbox" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="save"  value="<?php echo $idn?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="autosave_check" name="autosave_check" value="1">

    <br class="clear" /> <br />
    <div class="creator-buttons">
        <h2 class="subheader-creator"> Akce </h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;"  class='radiusz addchbox' id="ch" value="Checkbox field"><?php echo $langa['formc'][10];?>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td align='right'>
                    <input type="hidden" id="paths"  value="<?php echo $patH?>" /> 
                    <input type="submit" name='sub' value='<?php echo $langa['formc'][13]?>' id="saveT" class='dugme1 submitforms' style="float:right;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Its quite long code so just some parts.. Saving on button click works perfectly as for any other form.

Comment: The `data` variable holds whatever is returned from the AJAX request - the HTML error page in this case. It's not related to the content of the `serialized()` form data in any way.

Comment: You had better show us the PHP code in `form_creator.php` if you want any help

Comment: Autosave every 5 seconds. I hope you have only 2 users or a very big server farm planned

Comment: trying to do it as simple as possible since it doesnt work, will change it in a future

Comment: Of course, just trying to keep things light and friendly

Comment: how does form_creator.php look like?

Comment: Well if `sub` and `auto_savecheck` is not set you will return the HTML at the bottom of that script to the AJAX call. I have no idea from what you show why they would not be set, but thats what is happening.

Comment: from what i can tell you are ajaxing to the same file why?

Comment: Well it has 800 lines so I dont want to post it all. 

if((isset($_POST['sub'])) || (isset($_POST["autosave_check"]))) means if at least one of them is set, then save to db. Autosave_check should be set every time as its hidden field. Or not? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, no more time for the guessing game, bye

Comment: @madalinivascu I have saving to db and the form in the same file. I think I should link the file which has saving to db implemented, or not? Sorry I am doing this for the first time..